# Uploading image file to S3 using API gateway NodeJS

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to upload an image file to S3 using API Gateway. So it's a POST method where the body takes the image file using `form-data`. I wrote the lambda in TypeScript with the help of `lambda-multipart-parser`. It works fine locally but when i deploy it in AWS, the file size changes a bit and it seems the original file was not really uploaded properly.

my lambda code is

```
import * as parser from 'lambda-multipart-parser'
import { s3Upload } from '../helper/common'

export const test = async (event) => {
  console.log('starting------')
  console.log('EVENT', event)
  const result = await parser.parse(event)
  console.log(result.files)
  const file = result.files[0]
  console.log('FILE', file)

  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${Date.now().toString()}-${file.filename}`,
    Body: file.content,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    ACL: 'public-read',
  }
  console.log('S3 PARAMS', s3Params)
  const s3Content = await s3Upload(s3Params)
  console.log('S3 CONTENT', s3Content)
}
```

where i'm just calling the `s3Upload` from `helper`

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk'

export const s3Upload = async function (params) {
  let s3: S3
  if (process.env.IS_OFFLINE) {
    s3 = new S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    })
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        resolve(err)
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

this looks like a problem of the node package itself but i'm not sure! what are the other working ways i can achieve this objective which is to upload an image file to S3 using API gateway written in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information about your issue??

I took your code for testing locally. I found out that you need to instanciate the s3 again after the if is_offline.

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk'

export const s3Upload = async function (params) {
  let s3: S3
  if (process.env.IS_OFFLINE) {
    s3 = new S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    })
  }

  // Here is the change

  s3 = new S3({
    region: 'us-east-1', // for example
  });
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        resolve(err)
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

at least that worked for me. Also inside the lambda, also for local with serverless-offline, and also with an API Gateway, all with Typescript.

Hope this helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the module is not included in the lambda, try to do `npm init` and install the package in the folder where the lambda or the other option is, and it is more advisable to create a layer and put the package there.

Here the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#layers